# How do I initialize a view in H2

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2, spring-test

I have an entity which is mapped to an SQL view. I also have a spring data jpa repository configured for it. When the application runs everything works OK. However, the problem starts when I try to run my tests which uses an in-memory H2 database. I suspect the reason for this is that the view is not present when H2 starts, and it's probably treated as an independent entity, and hence spring boot configures it as an independent in-memory table.

The configuration for the H2 database is like below -

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
}
```

I tried putting the view definition in the `schema.sql` file in the test resource folder -

```
CREATE VIEW
    my_view
AS
    SELECT
         column_1,
         column_2
    FROM
        m
    INNER JOIN
        mu
    ON
        m.id = mu.m_id
    INNER JOIN
        u
    ON
        mu.id = u.mu_id
```

However, it does not help either. So whenever I call the configured JPA repository in my tests -

```
public interface MyViewRepository extends JpaRepository<MyView, Long> {}
```

like this -

```
myViewRepository.findAll()
```

it returns an empty list, even though I create all `m`, `mu`, and `u` entities in my tests using their related repositories before this search.

How can I configure H2 so that it picks up my view definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are declaring another DataSource to your integration or production environtment connecting to a database that it's already created and has the expected view declared.

When running tests and declaring your `@Bean` you probably should indicate what's the sql you want to be executed before the app starts. Spring Boot creates an empty H2 db.

Try this:

Assuming your `schema.sql` is in `src/test/resources`

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                                        .addScript("schema.sql")                                        
                                        .build();
}
```

Take care that your view is refering tables `m` and `mu` that should be declared also in the same script or another you want (you can concatenate as many addScript call as you want/need).

*Maybe your aproach of creating the entities through creating new objects with the `Repository` it's also correct, but I've never tried that, and the way I suggest you works for sure.*

Anyway, you can also check what's the content of the embed H2 database while running tests with the `h2-console`.

From Spring documentation at 29.4 (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html):

> The following should be true:
>
> - You are developing a web application
> - com.h2database:h2 is on the classpath
> - You are using Spring Boot’s developer tools

If you aren't using Spring Boot's developer tools, you also can do that:

Add `spring.h2.console.enabled = true` in  `application.properties` file

Then you should be able to use the H2 web console in the default path  `http://domain:port/contextPath/h2-console` and check what's the content at every moment.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Well, I wanted a cleaner solution than that. It would have been great if somehow I could force H2 to recognize my view mapping, but it seems that mapping an entity to view does not work :( .... oh well, I guess the benefit of this view outweighs this simple drawback. Thank you for your answer!